# i have found this error Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got numpy.ndarray)

Tags: python, spacy

```
     data = pd.read_csv("News.csv")
     Raw=data.headline
     New=Raw[1:3]



   for key,value in New.iteritems():
       doc = nlp(New.values)

       word_tokens=[token.text for token in doc]
       word_tokens
```

```
TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got numpy.ndarray)
```

Comment: I can't be certain given the short amount of code provided, but maybe you want to try `doc = nlp(value)` instead? From what I see, you are looping through the Pandas series to retrieve individual elements. If you use `New.values`, there seems to be no point in looping.

Comment: Thank you so much.It solve the error